# Can you help me add boxes on a separate line?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and HTML. I made 3 boxes next to each other and I want to have 2 more rows of 3 boxes per row. I can't seem to understand how to separate the rows. They always end up on the same row, distorted and I've been trying all morning to fix it. I will appreciate your help, thank you!

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 240px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.box .content {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: justify;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #fec10d;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #0077c0;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #b2d234;
}

.box img {
  position: relative;
  top: 1%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-175%);
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD" alt="Care">
      <div class="title">TEAMWORK</div>
      <div>Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates effectively.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD" alt="Care">
      <div class="title">BUILDS TRUST</div>
      <div>Gains the trust of others through honesty and authenticity. Shows consistency between his/her words and actions, upholds professional codes of conduct, acts in accordance with the company’s policies, delivers on promises, and takes personal responsibility
        for decisions, actions, and mistakes.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD" alt="Care">
      <div class="title">CARE FOR OTHERS AND INCLUSION</div>
      <div>Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates effectively.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: Or, put the next three boxes into a _new_ container element. (For responsive solutions that might need to display more or less boxes on one row at certain widths, the former is the better approach though.)

Comment: flex-wrap: wrap; add in your container class

Comment: Learn how to use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/), it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 20px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
  flex-basis: calc(32% - 6.67px); /* calculate flex-basis to account for gap */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.box .content {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #fec10d;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #0077c0;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #b2d234;
}

.box img {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

below code:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/team-work-linear-design_1284-35744.jpg?w=1480&t=st=1676633574~exp=1676634174~hmac=17f549203c31724f00ab9d71befd333b53daa983a4f6974cbdb1ec4dbc3c3ad5" alt="Care">
      <div class="title">TEAMWORK</div>
      <div>Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates effectively.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/team-work-linear-design_1284-35744.jpg?w=1480&t=st=1676633574~exp=1676634174~hmac=17f549203c31724f00ab9d71befd333b53daa983a4f6974cbdb1ec4dbc3c3ad5" alt="Care">
      <div class="title">BUILDS TRUST</div>
      <div>Gains the trust of others through honesty and authenticity. Shows consistency between his/her words and actions, upholds professional codes of conduct, acts in accordance with the company’s policies, delivers on promises, and takes personal responsibility
        for decisions, actions, and mistakes.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/team-work-linear-design_1284-35744.jpg?w=1480&t=st=1676633574~exp=1676634174~hmac=17f549203c31724f00ab9d71befd333b53daa983a4f6974cbdb1ec4dbc3c3ad5" alt="Care">
      <div class="title">CARE FOR OTHERS AND INCLUSION</div>
      <div>Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates effectively.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/team-work-linear-design_1284-35744.jpg?w=1480&t=st=1676633574~exp=1676634174~hmac=17f549203c31724f00ab9d71befd333b53daa983a4f6974cbdb1ec4dbc3c3ad5" alt="Care">
      <div class="title">TEAMWORK</div>
      <div>Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates effectively.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/team-work-linear-design_1284-35744.jpg?w=1480&t=st=1676633574~exp=1676634174~hmac=17f549203c31724f00ab9d71befd333b53daa983a4f6974cbdb1ec4dbc3c3ad5" alt="Care">
      <div class="title">TEAMWORK</div>
      <div>Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates effectively.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply these changes to resolve this issue :

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* add this style */

.boxes {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}
```

- 

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="content">
            <img
              src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD"
              alt="Care"
            />
            <div class="title">TEAMWORK</div>
            <div>
              Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support
              others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares
              knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates
              effectively.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="content">
            <img
              src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD"
              alt="Care"
            />
            <div class="title">BUILDS TRUST</div>
            <div>
              Gains the trust of others through honesty and authenticity. Shows
              consistency between his/her words and actions, upholds
              professional codes of conduct, acts in accordance with the
              company’s policies, delivers on promises, and takes personal
              responsibility for decisions, actions, and mistakes.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="content">
            <img
              src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD"
              alt="Care"
            />
            <div class="title">CARE FOR OTHERS AND INCLUSION</div>
            <div>
              Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support
              others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares
              knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates
              effectively.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="content">
            <img
              src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD"
              alt="Care"
            />
            <div class="title">TEAMWORK</div>
            <div>
              Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support
              others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares
              knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates
              effectively.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="content">
            <img
              src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD"
              alt="Care"
            />
            <div class="title">BUILDS TRUST</div>
            <div>
              Gains the trust of others through honesty and authenticity. Shows
              consistency between his/her words and actions, upholds
              professional codes of conduct, acts in accordance with the
              company’s policies, delivers on promises, and takes personal
              responsibility for decisions, actions, and mistakes.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="content">
            <img
              src="https://printeconline.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/Marketing/Group%20Marketing%20Folder/Brand/Brand%20Materials/Values/Icons/Icons/Printec_Values_Icons_White_500x500px/Printec_Care_Icon_White_500x500px.png?csf=1&web=1&e=paSbKD"
              alt="Care"
            />
            <div class="title">CARE FOR OTHERS AND INCLUSION</div>
            <div>
              Actively seeks opportunities to collaborate with and support
              others. Builds relationships across the organization, shares
              knowledge and experience, involve others and communicates
              effectively.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

- https://learncssgrid.com/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Can you explain why my answer is not correct?

Comment: Your previous answer I'd replied to didn't answer it as it said to just learn grid. That doesn't help the person. Your current answer doesn't explain to them what the code means. They're new to CSS so won't understand what you did, and how to make any changes.

Comment: My code is correct and I can't explain the cssgrid in my post, so I recommend to learn it on the https://learncssgrid.com/. but thank you